# Enable write permission inside PHP folder in Bluemix

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to deploy a PHP application on Bluemix, but the logs are written inside de tmp folder in the PHP folder.

But I'm getting write permission error.
How can I enable this folder to have write permission?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Bruno, could you please post the exact error you are seeing? `cf logs <app-name> --recent` would be ideal. Also are you trying to write to the log from your php code? a sample code that recreates the error would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Classically, "chmod 777" on the folder in question.  But a better approach might be to ID the user running PHP (for example, "Apache", "www", "nobody", etc.,) and set them as the owner of the folder in question, or make the folder *group* writeable by a group which said user (e.g. "nobody") is a member of.

Comment: I'm not being able do login via ssh in the Bluemix application. Is it possible? And if I change the folder permission in the machine, is there a possibility that it will be reseted?